# UWP Build fails when using 64BitCompiler

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, .net-native

I have a UWP Application which I build via a CI / CD pipeline on Azure DevOps in a Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019 Worker. As of late my store submission failed and the support told me to add the following flag to my CSPROJ to solve that issue:

```
<Use64BitCompiler>true</Use64BitCompiler>
```

Now with that flag the build on Azure DevOps fails with the following line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.3\tools\x64\ilc\Tools64\nutc_driver.exe @"d:\a\1\s\Src\MoneyFox.Uwp\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\MoneyFox.Uwp.rsp"' returned exit code 1 [d:\a\1\s\Src\MoneyFox.Uwp\MoneyFox.Uwp.csproj]
```

Interesstingly I can build locally without any issue

Here's the YAML of the build step:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build Windows Project'
  inputs:
    solution: Src/MoneyFox.sln
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\"   /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload  /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxBundle=Always'
    platform: x64
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

IlcRepo Link: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ang3D30bKDOhqNwdQsf0a3q1fAbfSg
Repository: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox
(The ilcRepro is based on the branch "native-repro")

Comment: Is there more content on the error? Does it give more lines?  I have found that on many occasions, a hosted build will fail when a private agent build will not. In many cases, there seems to be no rhyme or reason.

Comment: not that I can see. I added a link to the zip with all the log files. As far as I can see it calls .net native on line 9001 and posts the error on the next two with no furhter information.

Comment: Eek. This looks like a genuine optimizer bug to me (bug you never know until it's investigated :-)). Can you send me a mail to dotnetnative@microsoft.com? The most useful artifact you can share is an ilcRepro file and that's documented here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Comment: @MattWhilden Thanks for your answer. I sent you a mail.

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't see your mail. Did you send the zip as an attachment? Historically that's been a good way to make Exchange eat your mail :-)

You can also try mailing me more directly at <firstinitial><lastname>@<mycompany>.com

Comment: mmh, strange. I sent a OneDrive sharelink together with a link to the repository and this article here. I tried it again on your direct mail. Hopefully I got that one right. and as a fallback I added the same links to the original post.

Comment: @NPadrutt Have you successfully send the details to Matt?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT sorry, it seems my answer was not posted.. I haven't heared something from Matt. But I didn't receive an error from exchange and the details are also ine the ticket details for download.

Comment: @MattWhildenMSFT do you have any news here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was tracked down to the default agents for CI/CD not having enough memory (7GB) to complete compilation. We've looked at places where we can reduce memory pressure for these scenarios but that work wouldn't be available for a while as it's more structural than bug fix.

In the mean time there are two things worth trying to get unblocked.

1. Run the optimizer as single threaded. This helps reduce memory pressure by having only one copy of things to the optimizer to think about. Add this to your csproj file:
   <SingleThreadNUTC>true</SingleThreadNUTC>
2. Upgrade the hosted agent to a Standard_DS2_v2 or larger (that seems to work for most folks)

Comment: Your second point "upgrade the agent to `Standard_DS2_v2` if this is a hosted agent in Azure dev ops how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The SingleThreadNUTC thing didn't work for me at least, still failed with the same error.